# Assembly LoadFrom LoaderExecption

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I got some problem with Assembly.LoadFrom() method.

In the code, my WinForm application uses Assembly.LoadFrom() method to load a DLL file, it will try to get the class by using GetTypes() method and uses foreach to get each class name in order to match the input string which specifies the class name.

The situation was: (Insufficient reputation, see UML draft here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xN5Z.jpg)

The application used Assembly.LoadFrom() **Dll_X**, which contains **ClassA** and **ClassB**. **ClassB** uses some method from another referenced **Dll_Y** file in the solution, but **ClassA** didn't. These two class are independent.

I occasionally found that if I delete the **Dll_Y** file from the folder which contains the **Dll_X**, and intend to use **ClassA** only at runtime, there will be a LoaderException - can not find **Dll_Y**. I am wondering that **ClassA** did not use any method from **Dll_Y** and I was not creating **ClassB**, why the application was trying to find where **Dll_Y** is ?

The more confusing problem was: I made another try on **ClassC** in the same **Dll_X**, it uses some method in the referenced file **Dll_Z**, and I am sure that those three classes are indepent. When I deleted **Dll_Z** and trying to creating **ClassA**, everything works fine.

Can someone please tells me where might be a problem, or give some directions about this situation? Much Thanks!

Comment: Does ClassB *expose* anything it gets from DLL_Y?

Comment: No, **ClassB** has only one public method for calling, it only get things from **DLL_Y** in private methods.